# How to add pagination in TypeORM nestjs?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, backend, typeorm

As of now below method returning all the record. I need to return at a time 10 records. Please suggest what modification I need to do.

```
public async allSuppliersForBid(
    filter: FilterSupplierDto,
  ): Promise<[Supplier[], number]> {
    const { limit, page, query } = filter;
    const supplier = await this.supplierRepos.query(
      `SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE (suppliers."fullName" ILIKE '%${query}%' OR suppliers."companyName" ILIKE '%${query}%' OR suppliers.phone LIKE '%${query}%') AND (suppliers.status = 'active' AND suppliers."isVerified" = 'true' AND suppliers."isEnabled" = 'true' AND "assignCluster"<>'{}'::jsonb)`,
    );
    const count = supplier.length;
    return [supplier, count];
  }
```

this is `Pagination` file.

```
export class Pagination {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsPositive()
  @IsNumber()
  page: number = 1;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsPositive()
  @IsNumber()
  limit: number = 10;
}
```

I need to introduce pagination in this method. Any help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller.ts

```
@ApiBearerAuth()
    @ApiQuery({
        name: 'key',
        type: String,
        required: false,
      })
    @ApiOkResponse({
        status: HttpStatus.OK,
        description: "",
    })
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Get("inactive-user-pagination")
    findAllInActiveUser(
    @Query('limit', new IntValidationPipe()) limit: number,
    @Query('page', new IntValidationPipe()) page: number,
    @Query("key") key: string | ""
    ): Promise<ResponseDto> {
    const userDto = this.userService.findAllInActiveUser(
      page,
      limit,
      key
      );
    return this.responseService.toPaginationResponse(
        HttpStatus.OK,
        'Successful',
        page,
        limit,
        userDto,
      )
    }
```

service.ts

```
findAllInActiveUser =  async (page: number, limit: number,key:string): Promise<any> => {
        try {
          key = key ? key : "";
          let users = await this.userRepository.query(
              "rcon_get_all_inactive_users_pagination @page='" +
              page +
              "', @limit='" +
              limit +
              "', @key='" +
              key +
              "'"
            );
                users.map((data) => {
                    delete data.password;
                });
            const count = await this.userRepository.find({
                where: {...isInActive}
            });
            
            return this.conversionService.toPagination<
            UserEntity,
            UserDto
          >([users,count.length]);

            } catch (error) {
                throw new SystemException(error);
            }
        };
```

You can get a view of how to create a pagination